# Display a hidden div after a html form submit to show output

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a html form to collect name and place and after user submit the form, the out will display at bottom of the page using PHP echo

My requirement is,

> hide the `output div` before the form submit and after user enter data and submit, I have to make `output div` visible to display form output using PHP echo.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="main">
    <form id="main" name="main" action="#text" method="post">
        <div class="input">
            <div id="name">
                <div class="block">
                    <div class="input-quest">Your Name</div>
                    <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="nm" name="nm" type="text"  value="" /></span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="place">
                <div class="block">
                    <div class="input-quest">Your Place</div>
                    <div class="input-resp"><span><input  class="textbox" id="pl" name="pl" type="text" value="" /></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="submit">
            <input id="generate" type="submit" name="script" value="generate" />
            <input type="submit" id="clear" name="clear" value="clear" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="output">
        <?php $name = $_POST['nm']; $place = $_POST['pl']; echo "Hello, I am $name and I am from $place"; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

It contain the PHP echo codes at `output div` section.

I have searched for solution in previous questions and tried below methods mentioned there:

1.Added a inline CSS tag for `output div` to hide it

```
<div id="output" style="display: none;">
    <!-- echo php here -->
</div>
```

and added JavaScript to call function during submit

```
$('main').submit(function(){
    $('#output').show();  
});
```

It didn't work.

---

2.Tried with below JavaScript code

```
$('main').submit(function(e){
    $('#output').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

It didn't work.

---

3.Removed inline CSS for output div to hide and added the same to my CSS stylesheet

```
<div id="output">
```

and in stylesheet

```
#output{
    display:none;
}
```

and used below JavaScript code on submit

```
$('main').submit(function(){
    $('#output').css({
        'display' : 'block'
    }); 
});
```

It didn't work.

---

4. Added a `onclick` function along with the form submit

and submit button code:

```
<input  id="generate" type="submit"  name="script" value="generate" onclick="showoutput()"/>
```

and JavaScript:

```
showoutput(){
    $('#output').slideDown("fast");
}
```

and with

```
showoutput(){
    $('#output').show();  
}
```

It didn't work.

---

Please suggest a solution to do this.

Comment: set the display of the div with php. javascript wont work because the submit will reload the page

Comment: `$('main')` will not make any sense use `$('#main')` then try

Comment: Why do you need jQuery/CSS for this at all? If the form is being submitted, just check for the existence of both `$_POST['nm'] && $_POST['pl']`, and if true, echo them and the `div`

Comment: If you actually want it to submit and do what you want, you'll need to use ajax, otherwise, when you submit it will reload, or go to the `action` page. If you use ajax, have the submit using an `onclick` function. Inside the function you use, add the fadeOut/In you want.

Comment: @ billyonecan  : I didnt try with method because everytme it has to recreate a div id. Instead I thought of using show \ hide option.

Comment: @acr do you actually need to post the form at all? If all you want to do is display the values of `#nm` and `#pl` in `div.output`, just prevent the form from being submitted, and append the values to the `div`

Comment: @billyonecan   : I only need to display the values.

Comment: @acr have a look at [my second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019791/display-a-hidden-div-after-a-html-form-submit-to-show-output/18019962#18019962)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to use js/css for this at all. Just check if the variables were posted, and if they were, echo them (you'd have to set your form action to point to the same page):

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['nm']) && !empty($_POST['pl'])) { ?>
  <div class="output">
    Hello, I am <?php echo $_POST['nm']; ?>, and I am from <?php echo $_POST['pl']; ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

If you just want to display the name and place in `div.output`, without actually submitting the form, you could do:

```
$('#main').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from being submitted
  $('div.output').text('Hello, I am ' + $('#nm').val() + ', and I am from ' + $('#pl').val());
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWfR8/2/)

Comment: @ billyonecan : I prefer to use php codes because it will be easy for me to echo function.In your first example, it is not hiding the output div during initial page load.

Comment: The `div` won't even exist when the page is first loaded. It will only exist when the `if` condition is satisfied

Comment: @ billyonecan  : where I can add an else statement in first option ? like if the visitor not entered name and place, I need to display a message in output like "please enter above values". I tried to add else statement at bottom but that not working

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['nm'])) { ?>
<div class="output">
    <?php $name = $_POST['nm']; $place = $_POST['pl']; echo "Hello, I am $name and I am from $place"; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate page to process your `form` using javascript/jquery (ajax), and have it return the info you want, hide the `form` and show the `.output` div.

PHP Page:

```
<?php 

    $name = $_POST['nm']; 

    $place = $_POST['pl']; 

    echo "Hello, I am ".$name." and I am from ". $place; 
?>
```

The javascript/jquery would catch that as `responseText` and then use `innerHTML` on your `.output` div to put that `responseText`. You'd then use the JS/Jquery to hide the form and show the `.output`

Comment: Sorry if that's not clear, not sure if you're using jquery or javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually accomplish this entirely with php. The simplest method that I would use would be to make a hidden input with a given value. Once the user submits the form, that variable will exist and you can grab it in your php.

First you need to change the entire page to .php, and echo all of your html. then in the form, set the action to the name of the page so that it will send the variables to itself and then you can deal with them on the same page.

add this to the html:

```
<input type='hidden' name='display' value='display' />
```

In your php, add:

```
if (isset($_POST['display']){
     echo "make the div here";
}else{
     //don't show the div
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to reload the page for that to work? He's wanting the "output" to show his info and hide the form, but he'll need to get that info from another PHP page since php only loads once when the page loads.  AJAX is his only option.

Comment: When the user presses the submit button, the page actually reloads, but also sends the variables from the submitted form to the server for use in the php. This is easily seen in the URL of the site when the form is submitted with the "get" method. Post merely hides them. When the form is submitted, the variable "display" will exist in the php and allow this code to work.

Comment: But that doesn't help him hide his form, and would only work if he submitted his form to the same page.

Comment: It does help him hide his form because the html would never get echoed if the form hasn't been submitted yet. and yes it will only work if submitted to the same page, but that's the simplest way to do it and AJAX is overkill for this.

Comment: You don't even have to use ajax if you're not actually submitting anything. You don't need php either.

Comment: Then in that case why even have a form? you're moving out of the scope of the question. He was using a form and php and I gave him a solution using such. Its reasonable to assume that he used php because he plans to expand his code to interact with a database.

Comment: He said in his comments that he does not need to submit the form, just show the values. "billyonecan : I only need to display the values"

Comment: @ Optox, @jack :yes. I dont want to submit the form. I really want the user input data to display on the page along with some other  static data. It it very easy to display static data along with user entered data using php echo. I want to hide the static data during the initial stage.because without user entered form data, my static values doesnt make any sense. I am not really submitting the form to any database

Comment: @acr PHP runs when the page loads, so you cannot display user data without reloading and processing the data. It's fine if that's how you want it, but that's a limitation of PHP.

Comment: So the situation is very different than the one that I wrote my answer for.

Comment: I believe I can use echo to create a new output div after the form submission.

Comment: I thought you just said you don't want to submit the form though?